# How to add a table header to an existing jasper table component?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Is there a way to add a table header to an existing jasper report table?

I have an existing jasper report that contains a table component that does not have a table header.  I would like to add a table header now, but cannot find any way to do this without completely recreating the table.

Does anyone know of a way to add a Table Header to an existing jasper table component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options, add it directly in jrxml (xml) or use the IDE

### 1. Add directly to jrxml (go to source view)

In every `jr:column` you like to have a header add the `jr:tableHeader` tag as first element

```
<jr:column width="100" uuid="accf01ee-c512-4854-ae58-97dee667c054">
     <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30">
       <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="41f6fe02-194f-483e-ab7b-97a6061e2c27"/>
            <text><![CDATA[My header]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:tableHeader>
   ....
</jr:column>
```

### 2. Use the IDE directly

Double click the table component this make it possibile to edit it, navigate in outline to the header node, for every column you like header **create** the cell and then you will be able to drag a static or dynamic textfield to it.

[image]

Comment: +1 That did work.  Thank you.  I have 70+ columns in my table however, and it looks like for both methods I will have to do this once for each column.  I was hoping it would create a cell for every column, but perhaps that is wishful thinking.

Comment: Use the IDE, just select all the columns in the tree (use shift) and then select "Create Cell"